# How long is a HTTP response cached when it has no header specifying expiration?

Tags: http, caching, httpwebrequest

How long is a HTTP response cached with it has no header specifying expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

However, it usually won't be cahced at all.

Comment: By fluke or design this answer is amazingly accurate. A more complete answer would take several thousand words.